# how to append memory stream

Tags: c#, memorystream

```
 private MemoryStream ConvertWebChartChartToImage(WebChartControl chart)
{
    using (var pcl = new PrintableComponentLink(new PrintingSystem())
    {
        PageHeaderFooter = new PageHeaderFooter(new PageHeaderArea(new string[] { "A", "Header" },
            SystemFonts.DialogFont, BrickAlignment.Center),
            new PageFooterArea(new string[] { "B" },
                SystemFonts.DialogFont, BrickAlignment.Center)),
        Component = ((IChartContainer)chart).Chart,
        Landscape = true
    })
    {
        ((Chart)pcl.Component).OptionsPrint.SizeMode = DevExpress.XtraCharts.Printing.PrintSizeMode.Stret  ch;

        TransDistributionWCh.Legend.AlignmentHorizontal = LegendAlignmentHorizontal.Right;
        pcl.CreateDocument();
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        pcl.PrintingSystem.ExportToPdf(stream);
        return stream;
    }

}
    private void ConvertHTMLStringToPDF()
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var listChartControl = new List<WebChartControl>(new List<WebChartControl>
            {
                SuccTransDistributionWCh,
                AmountPerDayWCh,
                TransPerDayWCh,
                AmountPerTransPerDayWCh,
                ActiveTerminalPerDayWCh,
                TransNoWCh,
                TransAmountWCh,
                TransNoAmountWCh
            });
            foreach (var item in listChartControl)
            {

                var temp = ConvertWebChartChartToImage(item);
                stream.Write(temp.ToArray(), 0, temp.ToArray().Length);

            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Header", stream.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", ("Attachment") + "; filename=chart.pdf");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();}
```

i am use web control chart  dev express 
    and need convert web control chart to pdf
    my question:How do I add data to memory stream ?
    this code show last web chart 
    i suggest the zero number wrong
    stream.Write(temp.ToArray(), 0, temp.ToArray().Length);
    search the google and this  site Unfortunately problem not solved

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea, how `ExportToPdf` method works, but if it was written by human, there will be enough to use single stream:

```
private void ConvertWebChartChartToImage(WebChartControl chart, Stream stream)
{
    // ...
    pcl.PrintingSystem.ExportToPdf(stream);
}

private void ConvertHTMLStringToPDF()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // ...
        foreach (var item in listChartControl)
        {
            ConvertWebChartChartToImage(item, stream);
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note, that your original code leads to unnecessary memory allocations:

```
stream.Write(
    temp.ToArray(), // allocate temporary array, copy stream content into array
    0, 
    temp.ToArray().Length // allocate another array, copy stream content into array
    );
```

and doesn't dispose `MemoryStream` instance, returned from `ConvertWebChartChartToImage` method.

Also, if you want to copy content of one `Stream` to another `Stream`, there are [`CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/[`CopyToAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copytoasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.